# Swift - Combine two Entities in one List and Sort them by date

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I have a project with three entities: A One to Many Relationship form TransactionEntity to PurchaseEntity and SellEntity. I want to list the transactions of the two Entities inside one list and sort them by date or type of transaction(Purchase or sell). As an example:
01.01.2022 Purchase
02.01.2022 Purchase
03.01.2022 Sell
04.01.2022 Purchase.

I tried something like:

```
Struct Detail: View {
@StateObject var transaction: Transaction

var body: some View {

VStack {
ForEach(transaction.purchaseArray, transaction.sellArray) { transaction in

VStack {
Text(„\(transaction.purchaseArray.name ?? „“)„)
Text(„\(transaction.purchaseArray.value ?? „“)“)
Text(„\(transaction.purchaseArray.date ?? „“)“)
}
VStack {
Text(„\(transaction.sellArray.name ?? „“)„)
Text(„\(transaction.sellArray.value ?? „“)“)
Text(„\(transaction.sellArray.date ?? „“)“)
}

}
}

}
}
```

But that doesn’t work. But how can I display two entities in one list and sort them?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHHsl.png)

Comment: Make them conform to the same `protocol`

Comment: How can I use this in this Example? I‘m not experienced in Swift

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. Create a fully working example in a playground and then we can help.

Comment: Or you take a step back and redesign your model and use only one transaction entity with a type property that holds what kind of transaction it is.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

You have to create a `Protocol` and let all of your `Entities` conform to it.
Then you can define and `Array` and set its `Type` to the `Protocol`, which allows you to add all three Entities to it.

---

**Code**

```swift
protocol Entity: Hashable {
   var date: Date { get }
}

extension EntityA: Entity {
    var date: Date { a_purchDate }
}
extension EntityB: Entity {
    var date: Date { div_date }
}

struct Main: View {
    let entities: [any Entity]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(sortedEntities, id: \.self) { entity in 
            Text(entity.date.stringify()) // Note, that the Method stringify is not part of Foundation.
        }
    }

    private var sortedEntities: [any Entity] {
        return entities.sorted { $0.date < $1.date }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but get some Error messages. I've added them to my post

Comment: @SocialProcessing Sorry I forgot the ‚Struct Keyword‘. I updated my answer.

Comment: For the CoreData One-To-Many I had to create NSManagedObject Subclasses. So it gives an error with redeclaration. But when I add the var in this subclass there is an error that the ForEach cannot conform to Hashable. Furthermore the var for date inside the Entities is bound to core data attributes (EntityA: a_purchDate and EntityB: div_date) so what do I write for the value of the vars?

Comment: @SocialProcessing For `ForEach` to work, you have to conform to the `Hashable Protocol`. With the different `Date Names` in both `Subclasses`, you can simply add a computed Property to each of those that retrieves the underlying `Date`. I updates my answer with those changes.

Comment: Thank You for your answers! With extensions its working, but now I get an error with [any Entity] saying: "Protocol 'Entity' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements.

Comment: @SocialProcessing Yes that's actually a bit tricky since you cannot use an `any ProtocolType` inside a `SwiftUI ForEach`. You have to again separate both `Entities` into individual `Arrays` and use two different `ForEachs` or you have to create a `Container Type`.